# 'out' or 'ref' keywords do not work when declaring variables in parameters on VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

As the title says, the `out` keyword and the `ref` keyword doesn't seem to work on **VS2015** for types other than `System` types as parameters.

e.g.

```
public MyType Get(string key)
        {
            return _list.TryGetValue(key, out MyType myVariable) ? myVariable : null;
        }
```

This won't give me errors on **VS2017** but it does on **VS2015**. On **VS2015** it gives a syntax error as it's treating the type `MyType` as a variable.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

**UPDATE**

I changed the title from "**'out' or 'ref' keywords do not work as parameters for non system types on VS2015**" to "**'out' or 'ref' keywords do not work when declaring variables in parameters on VS2015**".

Also I was under the impression that this would work for `System` types such as `int` which is incorrect. It doesn't work irrelevant to what type is used.

Comment: It is a C# 7.0 feature

Comment: I believe this is a valuable question because other developers will eventually face the same issue. Specially when copying code from the internet

Comment: @met-u what about changing the title to `'out' or 'ref' keywords do not work as parameters for on VS2015`

Comment: @LuisFilipe Sure thing. However when I posted the question I thought the issue was that I was using a non system type. So my initial assumption that it would work for system types such as int is incorrect. I'll update my question to include that using system types are irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a [specific feature](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/) of `C# 7.0`

In VS2015 you are targeting, most likely, `C# 6.0`

Prior to `c# 7.0` you must declare the `out` variable before you use it as an `out` argument

In any given C# project go to

> Properties -> Build -> Advanced... -> Language Version

Comment: Such a face palm moment! Thanks for this. Spent a few hours wondering why it wouldn't work on a VS2015 machine.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring an `out` variable inline is a C# 7.0 feature.

In C# 6.0 and below you will have to use this:

```
public MyType Get(string key)
{
    MyType myVariable;
    return _list.TryGetValue(key, out myVariable) ? myVariable : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a C# 7.0 feature. If you want to compile it using Visual Studio 2015, you have to do it the old fashioned way.

```
public MyType Get(string key) {
    MyType variable;
    return _list.TryGetValue(key, out myVariable) ? myVariable : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a new feature in c#7.
Visual studio 2015 is using c#6 doesn't support declaring out variable like that.

Check [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/):

> In C# 7.0 we are adding out variables; the ability to declare a variable right at the point where it is passed as an out argument